# Unable to push my project due to merge conflict in github

Tags: git, github

I have to push my project in a remote repository , in that I have to submit my project branch wise with their names i.e all branches will have different projects with their names
But my problem is that I have submitted old project in new (web50/projects/2020/x/commerce) branch and my master branch have new project .Master branch can be empty But mistakenly I committed that

**I tried**

- Commited all the things when I try `git status`-

```
On branch web50/projects/2020/x/commerce
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

- To delete new branch so that I can remake a new branch and push my repo with-
  `git push origin --delete web50/projects/2020/x/commerce`
  But it says-

  ```
    ! [remote rejected] web50/projects/2020/x/commerce (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/web50/projects/2020/x/commerce)
  ```
- To force push my project to new branch with `git push origin web50/projects/2020/x/commerce  --force` It says-

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/web50/projects/2020/x/commerce.
remote: error: Cannot force-push to this protected branch
! [remote rejected] web50/projects/2020/x/commerce -> web50/projects/2020/x/commerce (protected branch hook declined)
```

Comment: It appears that you have some branch protection enabled in GitHub, you'd need to turn it off first. Then you will be able to force push the changes you want.

Comment: It is a cs50 authorised repo. I am doing a course from Edx of web development . Can I change the settings???

Comment: Explain to the repo's administrator (the teacher, I guess ?) your situation (you pushed a branch with the wrong name, correct ?) and ask him if he can delete the current branch from the remote repo.